# Outlook 2010 - Change the name of a menu tab

Tags: xml, ribbon, outlook-2010

I have been asked to write a script to change the name of a 3rd party tab on all Outlook 2010 users' ribbons.

The manual process would be to go to File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Select the Main tab on the right and choose rename.

I need to script this process, preferably with vbscript.  I understand that I cannot change the ribbon using the outlook.application class but I also understand the ribbon is at heart just an XML file.  I'd be happy to programmatically alter the XML file.

My questions are:

Is there a simpler method?

If not, how do I find the ribbon xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out how to do this - it turns out that when the ribbon tab is customised manually it creates a file in AppData\Local/Roaming\Microsoft\Office called xxx.officeUI where xxx can be one of many different filenames.  For customising the main ribbon in Outlook it is called olkexplorer.officeUI.

So all I had to do was find this customisation file and create an AD log in script that copies it into the correct folder depending on whether the user has a roaming or local profile...

For more info... [check this page out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704589.aspx#odc_office14_DeployCustomRibbon_ExampleofficeUICustomizationFile)